# Warning: Unknown props on styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new on styled components and I have the following question.

Lets say I have the following component:

```
const NavigationBar = Content.withComponent(Flex).extend`


display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 0 24px;

  height:  ${switchProp('size', {
    s: '40px',
    m: '50px',
    l: '70px',
  })};

  ${Text} {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    color: ${prop('theme.colors.navigation-text', '#000')};
  }

  ${H1}, ${H2}, ${H3}, ${H4}, ${H5}, ${H6}{
    color: #1474A4;
    padding: 0 24px;
    align-self: center;
    color: ${prop('theme.colors.navigation-text', '#000')};
  }
`;
export default NavigationBar;
```

Now when I use this component in story book or somewhere else, I get the following warning:

warning.js:33 Warning: Unknown props `primary`, `navigation`, `secondary`, on  tag. Remove these props from the element...

I read the documentation on https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html but I really I cannot fix or find a way to fix it. Can you provide me any input?

Comment: Upgrading your version of React to v16 would surpress the warning, but something is passing those props as (invalid) DOM-attributes.